# Elasticsearch dynamic synonym update

Tags: elasticsearch

We need to develop possibility of dynamic synonyms update without node restart or index close/open. So we decided to implement our own synonym functionality, basic idea is to have our own storage for synonyms and each time we process request, check query string for synonyms stored in our synonym storage. The question is, how implement query that returns all document that match query string or any of synonyms for any word(or phrase) from query string? Another important point, how all synonyms for any particular original word(or phrase) score only once?